# Filter files out of listdir that can't be read in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to look for a string, `userType` in all of the files inside of  a directory.

This code works on most files, but i have a file, `.DS_STORE` that seems to be encoded differently than the rest of the files.  I know the string I'm looking for is not in this file, but it breaks the program. How can I skip any files that can't be read?

Here is my code:

```
import os

path = "/home/me/Work/myprojectvirtualenv/myproject/homepage/templates/"

direct = os.listdir(path)

for item in direct:
    print("Checking " + item)
    if 'userType' in open(os.path.join(path ,item)).read():
        print("FOUND USERTYPE IN " + item)
```

Comment: Is it all dot files that throw this error?

Comment: If there are files that you know that throw an exception and you want to ignore those, why not `try/except` them and move on through your iteration of each file?

Comment: Wrap the read in a try/except block?

Comment: @MikeTung No, just the .DS_STORE.  I am pretty sure the reason is because it is encoded differently than the rest of the files.

Comment: @idjaw That worked.  You should post that as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `try/except` based on the *exception* that you know should be raised for the particular action you are performing. I'm pretty sure the exception you are most likely getting is `UnicodeDecodeError`. Alternatively, you could also open the file using "read-bytes" -> `rb`:

```
f = open('filename', 'rb')
```

More directly in your problem for using the try/except:

```
for item in direct:
    print("Checking " + item)
    try:
        if 'userType' in open(os.path.join(path ,item)).read():
            print("FOUND USERTYPE IN " + item)
    except WhateverTheExceptionIsYouWantToCatch:
        pass
```

Doing the above will raise when something unexpected happens so you can then determine how you want to proceed, otherwise, continue.

I would also suggest as an added bonus, to either explicitly call `.close` on your open, or even better and strongly recommended, use a context to handle the opening/closing for you, so you don't end up with a bunch of open files.

```
for item in direct:
    print("Checking " + item)
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(path, item)) as f:
            if 'userType' in f.read():
                print("FOUND USERTYPE IN " + item)
    except WhateverTheExceptionIsYouWantToCatch:
        pass
```

Finally, to the point of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361738/filter-files-out-of-listdir-that-cant-be-read-in-python-3/48361806#comment83710388_48361789) comment, you should probably ensure you even want to open certain files that you might not care about. Using the `glob` as suggested in that respective answer, you will probably filter down to files you actually care about.

### Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open)

It would be a good opportunity to also start making use of pathlib, as it provides great tools.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about not keeping files open.  Would it just keep the files open in memory if you don't close them?

Comment: @wanderer0810 Yes, so it is best to always close when you are done.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, I just want to say that I thought your answer was really informative and awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `os.listdir`, take advantage of swanky new python features like [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and (not new but part of path) [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob). Wit it you can look for files names matching a pattern:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path('/home/me/Work/myprojectvirtualenv/myproject/homepage/templates/')

for path in BASE_DIR.glob('**/*.txt'):
    with path.open() as f
        if 'userType' in f.read():
            print(f'found in: {path}')
```

This assumes the files you're interested in are `.txt`s, but you can tweak this to your needs.

Comment: I don't think it is a filename issue. It is the ability to actually read the file. In this case, I thinkg the `f.read()` will still raise the same error. But, ++ for the `Path` recommendation. :)

Comment: Yes but if you glob for only what you're interested in, it will exclude the `.DS_Store`. You shouldn't be opening files you can't read.

Comment: I agree. However, from my understanding, the OP wants to still read from DS_STORE.